# MongoDB raw java connection

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-authentication

I am trying to create a generic mongo connection component that will be used with different mongo DB instances. I managed to make it work with some code [like](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/mongodb_java.htm):

```
  // Creating a Mongo client 
  MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient( "localhost" , 27017 ); 

  // Creating Credentials 
  MongoCredential credential; 
  credential = MongoCredential.createCredential("sampleUser", "myDb", 
     "password".toCharArray()); 
  System.out.println("Connected to the database successfully");  
  
  // Accessing the database 
  MongoDatabase database = mongo.getDatabase("myDb"); 
  System.out.println("Credentials ::"+ credential);
```

I don't understand why it needs to specify the database in 2 places: `"myDb"`, once in the credential, and once while it does a `getDatabase`. More than that on my setup I need to specify a different DB on `createCredential`: "admin" in order to work. Why is the credential database different than the one I will run the query?

Comment: See these on MongoDB authentication: [Java Driver Reference on Authentication](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.12/driver/tutorials/authentication/) _and_ [MongoDB Secturity](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/security/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you inspect the code deeper, you will find the below compelling reasons.

This is the place where all the authenticators falls down.

```
private void authenticateAll(final InternalConnection internalConnection, final ConnectionDescription connectionDescription) {
        if (connectionDescription.getServerType() != ServerType.REPLICA_SET_ARBITER) {
            for (final Authenticator cur : authenticators) {
                cur.authenticate(internalConnection, connectionDescription);
            }
        }
    }
```

`authenticators` contains list of credentials. There are four implementations.

1. Default
2. Native
3. x509
4. sasl

> "myDb", once in the credential - why

Main reason to specify here, on which database the authenticate command has to be executed as each database can have different user name.

```
executeCommand(getCredential().getSource(), authCommand, connection);
```

> once while it does a getDatabase - why

It is altogether different. It returns `MongoDatabase` object which contains options to `read, write concerns, list of collections, create view, create collection`.